# C# - Can't get this seemingly simple web request working

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following powershell Web-Request that works correctly for sending a command to a PTZ camera:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "http://192.168.111.75/ajaxcom" `
-Method "POST" `
 -Headers @{
 "Accept"="application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
   "Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate"
   "Accept-Language"="en-US,en;q=0.9"
   "DNT"="1"
   "Origin"="http://192.168.111.75"
   "X-Requested-With"="XMLHttpRequest"
 } `
 -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" `
 -Body "szCmd=encodedStringHere"
```

I'm trying to recreate this in C# but I can't seem to get it to work..

I've tried a whole bunch of stuff but this is what my code looks like right now:

```
 public async static void Execute()
{
    using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    
   // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
   //     new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"));
   // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip, deflate"));
   // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("en-US,en;q=0.9"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("DNT", "1");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Origin", "http://192.168.111.75");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    string stringData = "{\"SysCtrl\":{\"PtzCtrl\":{\"nChanel\":0,\"szPtzCmd\":\"right_start\",\"byValue\":50}}}";
    var data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(stringData);
    KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Body", data.ToString());
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] { kvp });
    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://192.168.111.75/ajaxcom", content);
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

I don't know why I'm having so much trouble with this, any help is appreciated

Comment: "I can't seem to get it to work.." Some additional detail would be VERY helpful.

Comment: Each command I send gets a 200 OK response from the camera but it isn't moving the PTZ at all, the issue must be with the command I'm sending

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this part is one problem:

```
 string stringData = "{\"SysCtrl\":{\"PtzCtrl\":{\"nChanel\":0,\"szPtzCmd\":\"right_start\",\"byValue\":50}}}";
    var data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(stringData);
    KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Body", data.ToString());
```

You're calling ToString ( `data.ToString()` ) on a `Byte[]`. Not sure what you're expecting, but the output is going to be literally the string "System.Byte[]" Did you mean to convert it to base 64 or something?

Comment: Just to be sure.. the KVP is supposed to be "Body" as the key and "Encoded string" as the value, right? trying it with this added next: System.Convert.ToBase64String(data)

Comment: With the Convert.ToBase64 added it returns 200 again with no movement, and if I try a non-encoded string it does the same

Comment: "Body" isn't a key, it means the body of the HTTP POST. You're also not sending the szCmd parameter. Have you tried just doing :

`var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://192.168.111.75/ajaxcom?szCmd=" + stringData);` ?

Comment: This fixed my issue, thank you! Out of curiosity, is there another way to set the body through the C# api? Otherwise, thank you so much